# Can I go to another view without a StoryBoard segue? Just with a call from a view?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, segue

SO I would like to know if there is a possibility to make a call from a view in the code to go to another view, not using segue.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes. You can use `presentModalViewController` and a host of other methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, if you are using a navigation controller, you simply need to push onto the navigation controller:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:otherViewCon animated:YES];
```

Or, if you want a modal transition:

```
[self presentModalViewController:otherViewCon animated:YES];
```

This is all assuming `self` is a UIViewController.

To get `otherViewCon` from a storyboard designed view controller:

```
otherViewCon = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Other View"];
```

Comment: SO what I would like is not wire my views in the storyboard, make the calls from the code. And when you press the button with that call go to the view I want.

Comment: Is this in a navigation controller?  do you want to simply replace the current view controller with a different view controller?

Comment: I have some view controllers that are not wired with each other (no segue between them) and I want to press a button from one view to go to another view with only the code, without segues

Comment: @alex I'm talking about the structure of your app, I'm talking about how you want the views to transition visibly

Comment: @alex and why exactly would you not want to use segues?

Comment: Sorry Dan, because maybe I am not understanding your question. So I want my views transit by my code, not by the segues, because then the this transition between views is already fixed (I cannot change it anymore). I want that this transition between views can be programmed not blocked. Does it make sense?

Comment: And that is exactly what I told you how to do with my answer, that is code, there is absolutely nothing dependent on segues or storyboards in my answer

Comment: ah ok ok. I will try it right now and I will let you know Dan. Thank you so much for your patience Dan.

Comment: Last thing, how to declare otherViewCon? Because otherViewCon, is the view which I want to go right?

Comment: Do you get any debugger output from the crash?

Comment: 2012-07-13 14:30:16.055 RecolectaDatos[54035:10703] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x7373ba0>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'Other View''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x17a1022 0x28aacd6 0x5c0fef 0x28b0 0x17a2e99 0x19914e 0x1990e6 0x23fade 0x23ffa7 0x23f266 0x1be3c0 0x1be5e6 0x1a4dc4 0x198634 0x2e44ef5 0x1775195 0x16d9ff2 0x16d88da 0x16d7d84 0x16d7c9b 0x2e437d8 0x2e4388a 0x196626 0x2132 0x20a5 0x1)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

Comment: "Other View" was just an example string I used.  You have to set the identifier of your other view in interface builder, and then use that string to find it.  For example, I have a view controller in my storyboard identified as "Passcode Settings" so I instantiate it with `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Passcode Settings"];`

Comment: Ok, I solved that assigning the same identifier as my view. But now when I press the button I go to a view that is completely dark...

Comment: @alex I am unsure how to help you with that, there's a lot of variables.  Perhaps try taking this newfound knowledge, create a small test app and get the core of the view transition working with simpler cases.  And then try integrating your more complex case bit by bit to find what it is that is causing the problem.  Is it an image that isnt loading?  Is the view not loading for some reason?  Is there something in the custom view controller class that is making it all black?

Comment: It's just the view which I am calling the one is black... I only have two views. It's an easy code. Do you know somewhere where I can download this as an example?

Comment: BTW Dan its already working with what you sent me... I don't know why it was not working before. So thank you so much.

Comment: presentModalViewController is deprecated. use presentViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Example of presenting a popover:

```
    //Declare popover controller
    UIPopoverController *paparazzi;

   //Just some Interface Builder action (could be triggered by a button)
    - (IBAction)sigFocus:(id)sender
    {
        //A view controller being made from a xib file
        SigPopView *temp = [[SigPopView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SigPopView" bundle:nil];

        //Sets the view controller to be displayed
        paparazzi = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:temp];

        //Set size
        [paparazzi setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(480,179)];

        //Show controller
        [paparazzi presentPopoverFromRect:theSignature.frame inView:(UIView *)self.delegate permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: Oh sorry, you can't see the declaration because it's not a local variable. I'll edit that quick.

Comment: keep in mind, this method will only work on an iPad, popovers are not supported on iPhone

Comment: Also, SigPopView is a custom class. You would use what ever class you have that you want to present (and it needs a `.xib`) file. This is just a method I pulled out of the project I had open and edited slightly.